# how should i approach testing in ember?

Tags: testing, ember.js, jasmine

new to javascript and ember and i haven't built testing in this kind of application before.  i'm using jasmine and sinon so far.

i was building unit tests for the models for my ember app and that was straightforward. as soon as i got to controllers, i ran into issues.  i did not define a Router for the test app as i was just unit testing models.  however when i add a test for a Controller, Ember.Application.registerInjection gets called (i understand this is part of Ember's automated process with the router), but throws an error due to no router being defined.

if i define a minimal Router, ember tells me i must have an ApplicationView or application template defined on my app.  i understand that.

if i'm just wanting to run unit tests it seems that defining and rendering all the views of my regular app in the browser would be terribly slow as the tests accumulate.  i also realize that i do need to test my views at some point.

so this leads me to ask:

how do i efficiently run my unit tests that have no dependency on the view layer?

how do i do integration testing when the views are involved?

i'm reading about 'headless' testing but don't quite understand how to go about it, or what i should be using.  i'd like to stick with jasmine if possible.

general approaches, specific tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

My approach is to unit test models and integration test the rest. In general, unit testing anything beyond models becomes difficult since there's a lot of interaction. In the end, you want to test the behavior of your app as a whole so I'm ok with the integration testing approach.

Comment: thanks.  do you have any references or examples of integration testing in ember?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is an area that hasn't solidified yet. I've seen people use both RSpec + Capybara and also Konacha. If you aren't in a Ruby or Rails environment, you can look into using tools like Selenium or running your app in an iframe using jQuery to interact with it.